Вы бы поставили тут запятые? (Аргументация?)
1. Начальник направит(?) куда идти.
2. В те годы я работал(?) где придётся.


Начальник направит куда идти (= определит нужное направление).

От контекста зависит. Если начальник и в ироническом смысле, то запятой нет (устойчивый оборот в значении члена предложения). В остальных случаях придаточное предложение куда идти обычно отделяется запятой.

В те годы я работал, где придётся.

Решение зависит от контекста. Если предложено закончено, но дальше в тексте тема продолжается (дается  описание мест работы), то запятая нужна.
Сравнить: В те годы я работал где придётся и часто менял профессии.
Примеры с разными решениями
Он посадит самолёт где придётся (= в любом месте), с риском расплющить его о землю. До совхоза шли большой компанией целых три дня, ночевали где придётся (= в разных местах,  влияние однородных сказуемых). Но: Измученные люди спали, где придётся – кто на полке, кто на вещах, а кто и прямо на полу, подстелив под себя всё те же газеты.
Розенталь  § 41. Цельные по смыслу выражения
Данное правило основано на том, что фразеологический оборот 
не образует придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения 
и обычно эквивалентен члену предложения. Так, в сочетании 
говорит об этом где только может выделенные слова имеют 
значение ‘везде’.
Если же какое-либо из приведенных выше и аналогичных 
словосочетаний употреблено не в качестве фразеологизма, то 
оно может образовать придаточную часть (обычно неполное 
предложение) и быть выделено запятыми: Просторечные слова 
стали употреблять где нужно и не нужно — ‘везде’; Поставить, 
где нужно, недостающие знаки препинания — ‘где это нужно’.


Спасибо! Измученные люди спали, где придётся – кто на полке... После "придётся" не нужна запятая закрыть придаточное?

Думаю, что нет. Здесь тесная связь между поясняющей присоединительной конструкцией (где именно)    и придаточным. Единый знак (запятая и тире) с увеличенной паузой не подойдет. Такие конструкции хорошо решать по Лопатину, где допускается выбор знака между двумя блоками.
